# Joomla 1.5 can't save component parameters

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have custom coded Joomla v1.5 component. In administrator zone I change its parameters, but when I taking param values in my code I get only default values, but not the new as I set in components admin zone params window.

```
global $option;
$params = &JComponentHelper::getParams( $option );

print_r($params);
```

The output looks like this:

```
JParameter Object
(
    [_raw] => param_1=This is changed value of the param 1
param_2=20
param_3=This is changed value of the param 3
    [_xml] => 
    [_elements] => Array
        (
        )

    [_elementPath] => Array
        (
            [0] => /home/x/domains/xyz.com/public_html/libraries/joomla/html/parameter/element
        )

    [_defaultNameSpace] => _default
    [_registry] => Array
        (
            [_default] => Array
                (
                    [data] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [param_1] => some default value 1
                            [param_2] => 10
                            [param_3] => some default value 3
                        )

                )

        )

    [_errors] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

How you in output, param raw data changes, but the data field does not. So what's the problem ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the problem. So when I create a menu link to my component view, it duplicates the component parameters in menu item params list. So it overrides the main component parameters. That's why if I change param value in components param window(in admin zone), I get only param values that are in menu items window. Also found some more information about it in Joomla forum: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=485837